# ansible include_vars issue with ignore_files

Tags: python, ansible

I am trying `include_vars` in a playbook, But i want to exclude one file and include rest of them. Tried `ignore_files: 'b.yml'` But it is not loading any files, when removed its including all files.

```
# tree
.
├── myvars
│   ├── a.yml
│   └── b.yml
└── test.yml

1 directory, 3 files
# cat test.yml
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        dir: 'myvars'
        ignore_files: 'b.yml'
        extensions: ['yml']

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ name }}"


# cat myvars/a.yml
---
name: IronMan
#
```

see the include vars output, none of the file is loaded.

```
# ansible-playbook test.yml -i "localhost," -c local -vv

PLAYBOOK: test.yml ***************************************************************************************************************************
1 plays in test.yml

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]
META: ran handlers

TASK [include_vars] **************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /root/test.yml:4
ok: [localhost] => {"ansible_facts": {}, "ansible_included_var_files": [], "changed": false, "failed": false}

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /root/test.yml:9
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'name' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/root/test.yml': line 9, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - debug:\n      ^ here\n\nexception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable'>\nexception: 'name' is undefined"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/root/test.retry

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Comment: I guess there is a bug in the module itself. https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/29135 tested the same for myself and it doesn't worked for me as well. Hope you are using 2.3 version of ansilbe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always check parameter type:

```
- ignore_files
    List of file names to ignore.
    [Default: None]
    version_added: 2.2
```

Change your arg to be a list:

```
- include_vars:
    dir: 'myvars'
    ignore_files: ['b.yml']
    extensions: ['yml']
```